# Parsing custom log files

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0, logfile-analysis

I have a log file (*.log) I wish to parse and query as below:

```
Line 33043: 17/07/2016;13:26:45;GetMasterOrderNo;Master Order No is :  1117103907 for SoSupplierOrderNo, 1117103907
Line 33048: 17/07/2016;13:26:45;AddAutoPurchHdr;Could not save PurchHdr record - The supplier order number has already been used in Delivery Note No.1117103907 (Order No.1117103907), Supplier SupplierName(51)
Line 33049: 17/07/2016;13:26:45;ImportASN;ConvertASNFiles: Failed to import GRN1171_0000700384_1117103907.xml.  Could not save PurchHdr record - The supplier order number has already been used in Delivery Note No.1117103907 (Order No.1117103907), Supplier SupplierName(51)
```

What I want to do is to split each line with headers as follows:

- Line,
- Date,
- Time,
- Type,
- Description

...so I can then perform queries on this.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: You have semi-colon separated fields. You could parse it as CSV with a semi-colon delimiter.

Comment: @ChrisDent That was my first attempt but e. g. the line isn't separated by a semi-colon and also the Description could include semicolons...

Answer (score 6):

You could use a regex to capture those fields:

```
$content = Get-Content 'your_log_path' -raw
$regex = 'Line\s+(\d+):\s+([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);(.+)'
[regex]::Matches($content, $regex) | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Line = $_.Groups[1].Value
        Date = $_.Groups[2].Value
        Time = $_.Groups[3].Value
        Type = $_.Groups[4].Value
        Description = $_.Groups[5].Value
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Line        : 33043
Date        : 17/07/2016
Time        : 13:26:45
Type        : GetMasterOrderNo
Description : Master Order No is :  1117103907 for SoSupplierOrderNo, 1117103907

Line        : 33048
Date        : 17/07/2016
Time        : 13:26:45
Type        : AddAutoPurchHdr
Description : Could not save PurchHdr record - The supplier order number has already been used in Delivery Note No.1117103907 (Order No.1117103907), Supplier SupplierName(51)

Line        : 33049
Date        : 17/07/2016
Time        : 13:26:45
Type        : ImportASN
Description : ConvertASNFiles: Failed to import GRN1171_0000700384_1117103907.xml.  Could not save PurchHdr record - The supplier order number has already been used in Delivery Note 
              No.1117103907 (Order No.1117103907), Supplier SupplierName(51)
```

---

**Regex:**

```
Line\s+(\d+):\s+([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);(.+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 6):

A little fix to Martin's very good answer. [PSCustomObject] construction would not work on powershell v2 host.

```
$content = Get-Content 'your_log_path' -raw
$regex = 'Line\s+(\d+):\s+([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);(.+)'
[regex]::Matches($content, $regex) | ForEach-Object {
    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Line -Value $_.Groups[1].Value
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Date -Value $_.Groups[2].Value
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Time -Value $_.Groups[3].Value
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Type -Value $_.Groups[4].Value
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Description -Value $_.Groups[5].Value
    $obj
}
```

Comment: True, I missed the version! +1

Comment: But the `-Property` hashtable argument should work, right?

Comment: V2 is what is on my desktop, though I can always run it off a server running V4

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex capture groups with names to make the hashtable keys for the custom object:

```
Get-Content log.txt | ForEach {
    $_ -match '^Line (?<Line>\d+): (?<Day>..)/(?<Month>..)/(?<Year>....);(?<Time>.*?);(?<Type>.*?);(?<Message>.*)$'

    # Cast date and line to useful types (optional)
    $Matches['Date'] = Get-Date ($Matches['Year']+'-'+$Matches['Month']+'-'+$Matches['Day']+' '+$Matches['Time'])
    $Matches['Line'] = [int]$Matches['Line']

    New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property $Matches
}
```